# Unable to display Struts2 fieldError

Tags: struts2, struts-validation

I have created the index.jsp which send action request

```
 <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=./radioButton.action">
```

After completing this the request is forwarded to **radio.jsp**. In this one i am showing country, state list etc.. (so i am **redirecting** for this from **index.jsp**).
Now **i am imposing validations to this form**. **i have created the .xml correctly** for validation.When the validation fail it will be redirected to ./radioButton.action

```
  <result name="input" type="redirectAction">radioButton</result>
```

I have created one interceptor which extends **MethodFilterInterceptor**, for this to keep the action errors in session scope which having the follow logic in after() method.

```
if (fieldErrors != null && fieldErrors.size() > 0)
        {
            Iterator it = fieldErrors.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue().toString());
            }
            session.put(FIELD_ERRORS_KEY, fieldErrors);
        }

 public static final String FIELD_ERRORS_KEY    = "RedirectMessageInterceptor_FieldErrors";
```

i have configured the interceptor in my .xml as below

```
<interceptors>
    <interceptor name="redirectMessage"  class="com.daya.message.RedirectMessageInterceptor" />

       <interceptor-stack name="sessionStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="redirectMessage" />
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
       </interceptor-stack>
  </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
```

I am getting the **error message on my console befor putting into session scope**. The output printed in console is

```
userName = [User Name is required to login]
password = [Password is required to login]
```

I am using the below tag to display the field error

```
<s:fielderror></s:fielderror>
```

But in the jsp after redirect (when validation failed) messages are not getting display.

**Client side validation is working well. I disabled javascript for checking server side validation**

Comment: How are you fetching the messages from the session again? I don't understand why you're duplicating existing functionality either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Struts providing a way handle this using [MessageStoreInterceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/message-store-interceptor.html) but i don't know why you are doing it manually.

Comment: Then override the existing functionality rather than create a new one.

Comment: @DayanandaEswar by teling us why you want to implement your own we can provide better answers (or suggest a better way).